# Slides is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides, page-numbering

I'm doing my first steps in Google Apps script, and trying to add SlideNumbers with a code that I found.
Each slide has textbox with "{{PgNm}}" text, and I'm trying to replace this with the pattern SlideNum/NumOfSlides.
When I run it, I get "Slides is not defined" message.
Maybe someone can help me?

```
function ReplacePgNm() {
 var MainPPT=SlidesApp.openById(MainPPT_ID);
 var Main=MainPPT.getSlides();
 var len = Main.length;

 var i = 1;

 Main.forEach(function(slide) {
    var pageElementId = slide.getObjectId();
    console.log(pageElementId);
    var resource = {
      requests: [{
        replaceAllText: {
          pageObjectIds: [pageElementId],
          replaceText: i+"/"+len,
          containsText: { matchCase: true, text: "{{PgNm}}" }
        }
      }]
    };

  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(resource, MainPPT.getId());
  i++;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that the reason for your current issue of `Slides is not defined` is due to that you have never enabled Slides API at Advanced Google services.
- And, in your script, `Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### 1. Enable Slides API.

[Please enable Google Slides API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

#### 2. Modified script.

```js
function ReplacePgNm() {
  var MainPPT_ID = "###"; // Please set your Google Slides ID.

  var MainPPT = SlidesApp.openById(MainPPT_ID);
  var Main = MainPPT.getSlides();
  var len = Main.length;
  var requests = Main.map((slide, i) => ({
    replaceAllText: {
      pageObjectIds: [slide.getObjectId()],
      replaceText: (i + 1) + "/" + len,
      containsText: { matchCase: true, text: "{{PgNm}}" }
    }
  }));
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({ requests }, MainPPT_ID);
}
```

Or, I thought that in your script, your goal can be achieved by only the Slides service (SlidesApp) without using Slides API. When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows. In this case, Slides API is not required to be enabled.

```js
function ReplacePgNm() {
  var MainPPT_ID = "###"; // Please set your Google Slides ID.

  var MainPPT = SlidesApp.openById(MainPPT_ID);
  var Main = MainPPT.getSlides();
  var len = Main.length;
  Main.forEach((slide, i) => slide.replaceAllText("{{PgNm}}", (i + 1) + "/" + len));
}
```

#### References:

- [Method: presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)
- [ReplaceAllTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#replacealltextrequest)
- [replaceAllText(findText, replaceText) of Class Slide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#replaceAllText(String,String))